# How to index a list using for loops?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of words.

```
mylist = ["aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu"]
```

I want to turn each element in the list into a sublist and add to each a number so that each entry is indexed. So it should output

```
[[1, 'aus'], [2, 'ausser'], [3, 'bei'], [4, 'mit'], [5, 'noch'], [6, 'seit'], [7, 'von'], [8, 'zu']]
```

I know how to do such a thing with a `while` loop

```
mylist = ["aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu","aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu","aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu"]

mylist2

i=0

while i <= 10:
    mylist2.append([i,mylist[i]])
    i = i +1

print(mylist2)
```

But I want to use the following kind of structure with a `for`-loop:

```
mylist = ["aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu"]

outlist =[[1,word] for word in mylist]
print(outlist)
```

I'm not sure how to do that with a `for`-loop. Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: You could use enumerate: `list(enumerate(mylist, 1))`

Comment: There is a reason people keep removing tags from your titles. Please stop writing them. Also don't use quote formatting for things that aren't quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the inner parts to be lists then you can cast the `enumerate` result to a list inside a list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = ["aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu"]
>>> [[idx, item] for idx, item in enumerate(mylist, 1)]
[[1, 'aus'],
 [2, 'ausser'],
 [3, 'bei'],
 [4, 'mit'],
 [5, 'noch'],
 [6, 'seit'],
 [7, 'von'],
 [8, 'zu']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
>>> mylist = ["aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu"]
>>> list(enumerate(mylist, 1))

[(1, 'aus'),
 (2, 'ausser'),
 (3, 'bei'),
 (4, 'mit'),
 (5, 'noch'),
 (6, 'seit'),
 (7, 'von'),
 (8, 'zu')]
```

If you need a list of lists instead of tuples, you can do

`list(map(list(enumerate(mylist, 1))))`

or

`[[number, word] for number, word in enumerate(mylist, 1)]`

Comment: change ```  list(enumerate(mylist, 1) ``` to ``` list(enumerate(mylist, 1))```

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerate:

```
[list(element) for element in list(enumerate(mylist, 1))]
```

Comment: You don't need the `list` in `list(enumerate(mylist, 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I think you are looking for.

```
list1 = ["aus","ausser","bei","mit","noch","seit","von","zu"]
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list2 += [[i+1, list1[i]]]
print (list2)
```

Uses a for loop to go through each item in list 1 and the indexes in list 1 and the adds 1 to the index so that it doesn't start with 0.